# How to map network_adapters and storage blocks using Packer vSphere-ISO HCL2 (JSON syntax)

Tags: json, packer

I'm trying to build a VM using the HCL2 JSON syntax. It's not a deal breaker if this is impossible; I just prefer to use the JSON syntax as I find it easier and cleaner to manipulate programmatically. I keep running into the issue of adding storage and network_adapters complex types. I believe both keywords are of type list(map(string)). Here is what I have currently:

**var-defs.pkr.json**:

```
{
    "variable": {
        "network_adapters": {
            "description": "List of network adapters to add to the VM.",
            "type": "list(object({ network=string, network_card=string }))",
            "default": [
                {
                    "network": "Infra",
                    "network_card": "vmxnet3"
                }
            ]
        },

        "storage": {
            "description": "List of virtual disks to add to the VM.",
            "type": "list(object({ disk_controller_index=number, disk_size=number, disk_thin_provisioned=bool }))",
            "default": [
                {
                    "disk_controller_index": 0,
                    "disk_size": 65536,
                    "disk_thin_provisioned": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried setting the type as `"list(map(string))"`.

**var.auto.pkrvars.json**:

```
{
    "network_adapters" : [
        {
            "network": "Infra",
            "network_card": "vmxnet3"
        }
    ],

    "storage" : [
        {
            "disk_controller_index" : 0,
            "disk_size" : 65536,
            "disk_thin_provisioned" : true
        },

        {
            "disk_controller_index" : 0,
            "disk_size" : 65536,
            "disk_thin_provisioned" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried the following approaches with no success:

**source.pkr.json (direct assignment)**:

```
{
    "source" : {
        "vsphere-iso" : {
            "hcl2-json-build-vm" : {
                "network_adapters" : "${var.network_adapters}",
                "storage" : "${var.storage}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**source.pkr.json (splatting)**:

```
{
    "source" : {
        "vsphere-iso" : {
            "hcl2-json-build-vm" : {
                "network_adapters" : [
                    {
                        "network" : "${var.network_adapters[*].network}",
                        "network_card" : "${var.network_adapters[*].network_card}"
                    }
                ],
                
                "storage" : [
                    {
                        "disk_controller_index" : "${var.storage[*].disk_controller_index}",
                        "disk_size" : "${var.storage[*].disk_size}",
                        "disk_thin_provisioned" : "${var.storage[*].disk_thin_provisioned}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**source.pkr.json (dynamic blocks)**:

```
{
    "source" : {
        "vsphere-iso" : {
            "hcl2-json-build-vm" : {
                "dynamic" : {
                    "network_adapters" : {
                        "for_each" : "${var.network_adapters}",
                        "content"  : {
                            "network" : "${network_adapters.network}",
                            "network_card" : "${network_adapters.network_card}"
                        }
                    },

                    "storage" : {
                        "for_each" : "${var.storage}",
                        "content"  : {
                            "disk_controller_index" : "${storage.disk_controller_index}",
                            "disk_size" : "${storage.disk_size}",
                            "disk_thin_provisioned" : "${storage.disk_thin_provisioned}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help point out my mistakes, or let me know if this is even possible currently? Much appreciated!

edit:
To document better (and give the thread a bump, let's be honest) the errors I get when trying to define network_adapters and storage in user variables and using the splatting method are:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type
  on source.pkr.json line 39:
  (source code not available)
with var.storage as tuple with 2 elements.
Inappropriate value for attribute "disk_controller_index": number required.

Error: Incorrect attribute value type
  on source.pkr.json line 40:
  (source code not available)
with var.storage as tuple with 2 elements.
Inappropriate value for attribute "disk_size": number required.

Error: Incorrect attribute value type
  on source.pkr.json line 41:
  (source code not available)
with var.storage as tuple with 2 elements.
Inappropriate value for attribute "disk_thin_provisioned": bool required.

Error: Incorrect attribute value type
  on source.pkr.json line 32:
  (source code not available)
with var.network_adapters as tuple with 1 element.
Inappropriate value for attribute "network": string required.

Error: Incorrect attribute value type
  on source.pkr.json line 33:
  (source code not available)
with var.network_adapters as tuple with 1 element.
Inappropriate value for attribute "network_card": string required.
```

The string interpolation doesn't seem to work as expected. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of tinkering, I was able to get the suggestion made by SwampDragons [here](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/hcl2-json-syntax-network-adapters-and-storage-blocks/24646/3?u=howardj99) to work. The final implementation looks something like this, in case anyone runs into the same issue in the future:

###### var-defs.pkr.json

```
...
"network_adapters": {
    "description": "List of network adapters to add to the VM.",
    "type": "list(map(string))",
    "default": [
        {
            "network": "LLE-Infra",
            "network_card": "vmxnet3"
        }
    ]
},

"storage": {
    "description": "List of virtual disks to add to the VM.",
    "type": "list(map(string))",
    "default": [
        {
            "disk_controller_index": 0,
            "disk_size": 65536,
            "disk_thin_provisioned": true
        }
    ]
}
...
```

###### var.auto.pkrvars.json

```
...
"network_adapters" : [
    {
        "network"      : "Infra",
        "network_card" : "vmxnet3"
    }
],

"storage" : [
    {
        "disk_controller_index" : 0,
        "disk_size" : 65536,
        "disk_thin_provisioned" : true
    },

    {
        "disk_controller_index" : 0,
        "disk_size" : 65536,
        "disk_thin_provisioned" : true
    }
]
...
```

###### source.pkr.json

```
...
"dynamic" : {
    "network_adapters" : {
        "for_each": "${var.network_adapters}",
        "content" : {
            "network": "${network_adapters.value.network}",
            "network_card": "${network_adapters.value.network_card}"
        }
    },

    "storage" : {
        "for_each" : "${var.storage}",
        "content"  : {
            "disk_controller_index": "${storage.value.disk_controller_index}",
            "disk_size": "${storage.value.disk_size}",
            "disk_thin_provisioned": "${storage.value.disk_thin_provisioned}"
        }
    }
}
...
```